# Issue in changing directory while doing ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have the following scenario, I have script that runs bash script on another remote machine

The command to ssh is

```
ssh knode@192.18.48.0 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

test.sh

```
#/bin/sh
bash ./trigger.sh
```

trigger.sh (Remote server)

```
docker build -t nginx .
```

I need to change the directory before executing the script `trigger.sh`. For instance like this:

```
ssh knode@192.18.48.0 'cd /pipeline' 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

I tried with cd but I am getting error bash line 0:cd: too many arguments

Help is highly appreciated how to accomplish this, or is there any other way for the above scenario.

Comment: Can't you add the `cd` to either `test.sh` or `trigger.sh`?

Comment: Maybe `ssh knode@192.18.48.0 'cd /pipeline && bash -s' < test.sh`?  (untested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `cd` to the ssh command:

```
ssh knode@192.18.48.0 'cd /pipeline && bash -s' < test.sh
```

Alternatively, you can add it to either one of the scripts you call. So either `test.sh`:

```
#/bin/sh
cd /pipeline
bash ~/trigger.sh
```

Or `trigger.sh`:

```
cd /pipeline
docker build -t nginx .
```